# The $m$-order submatrixs respectively from two $m\times n$ matrixs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

> Suppose that $A,B\in Mat_{m\times n}(\mathbb{C}),m\leq n.\det(A\overline{A^{'}})\ne 0,\det(B\overline{B^{'}})\ne 0.$
>
> Show that
> $$  \exists C\in Mat_{m\times m}(\mathbb{C}),s.t. B=CA. \Longleftrightarrow $$$$\exists \lambda\in \mathbb{C},s.t. \forall 1\leq i_{1}< i_{2}<\cdots<i_{m}\leq n,$$
> $$ \det (B\begin{pmatrix}
>  1&  2&  \cdots& m\\ 
>  i_{1}&  i_{2}&  \cdots& i_{m} 
> \end{pmatrix})=\lambda\cdot\det( A \begin{pmatrix}
>  1&  2&  \cdots& m\\ 
>  i_{1}&  i_{2}&  \cdots& i_{m} 
> \end{pmatrix}).$$

$A\in Mat_{m\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ means $A$ is an $m$-by-$n$ complex matrix.

$\overline{A^{'}}$ means the conjugate transpose of $A$.

$A\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  2&  \cdots& m\\ 
 i_{1}&  i_{2}&  \cdots& i_{m} 
\end{pmatrix} $ is a submatrix of $A$ ,in which the set of row indices is $\{1,2,\cdots ,m\} $ and the set of column indices is$\{i_{1},i_{2},\cdots ,i_{m}\}$.

---

$\Rightarrow_{.}$   It is easy to verify.

$\Leftarrow_{.}$ In order to simplify this question, I let $m=2,n=3.$$A=(a_{ij})_{2\times 3},B=(b_{ij})_{2\times 3}.$
Then
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
 b_{11}& b_{12} \\ 
 b_{21}& b_{22}
\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\cdot \det\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11}& a_{12} \\ 
 a_{21}& a_{22}
\end{pmatrix},$$
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
 b_{11}& b_{13} \\ 
 b_{21}& b_{23}
\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\cdot \det\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11}& a_{13} \\ 
 a_{21}& a_{23}
\end{pmatrix},$$
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
 b_{12}& b_{13} \\ 
 b_{22}& b_{23}
\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\cdot \det\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{12}& a_{13} \\ 
 a_{22}& a_{23}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

How can I find a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
 c_{11}&c_{12} \\ 
 c_{21}&c_{22} 
\end{pmatrix},$
satisfying the following equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
 \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\lambda=\det\begin{pmatrix}
 c_{11}&c_{12} \\ 
 c_{21}&c_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}; &  \\ 
 \begin{pmatrix}
 b_{11}&  b_{12}& b_{13}\\ 
 b_{21}&  b_{22}& b_{23}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 c_{11}&c_{12} \\ 
 c_{21}&c_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11}&  a_{12}& a_{13}\\ 
 a_{21}&  a_{22}& a_{23}
\end{pmatrix}.& 
\end{cases}
?$$

Comment: Maybe it helps you to prove first that there exists such a $C$ if and only if $\ker A\subset\ker B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = [A_1\;A_2]$ and $B = [B_1\;B_2]$ and assume that $A_1$ and $B_1$ are invertible. If this is not the case, rearrange the columns. Set $D := \det(A_1)$. Then $\det(B_1) = \lambda D$. Define $C := B_1A_1^{-1}$. Then $CA_1 = B_1$.

Now, let $a$ be an arbitrary column in $A_2$ and $b$ the corresponding one in $B_2$. We have to prove that $Ca = b$. Let $x := A_1^{-1}a$ and $y := B_1^{-1}b$. Let $j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and let $A_1'$ be the matrix $A_1$ with missing $j$-th column. Define $B_1'$ accordingly. Then (denoting by $A_1^k$ the $k$-th column of $A_1$)
\begin{align*}
\det(A_1'|a)
&= \det(A_1'|A_1x) = \det(A_1'|\sum_{k=1}^mx_kA_1^k) = \sum_{k=1}^mx_k\det(A_1'|A_1^k)\\
&= x_j\det(A_1'|A_1^j) = (-1)^{m-j} x_j\det(A_1) = (-1)^{m-j}Dx_j.
\end{align*}
Analogously,
$$
\det(B_1'|b) = (-1)^{m-j}y_j\det(B_1) = (-1)^{m-j}\lambda Dy_j.
$$
Therefore,
$$
(-1)^{m-j}\lambda Dy_j = \det(B_1'|b) = \lambda\det(A_1'|a) = (-1)^{m-j}\lambda Dx_j.
$$
This implies $y = x$ and thus $Ca = CA_1x = B_1 x = B_1y = b$.

Comment: Wow, it's a  kind of  elegant proof ! Specially, some  skills  and  strategies are  spent  wisely  in  doing  it.  Thanks a lot. +1

Comment: Thanks so much. It took me some time to figure out the structures here. But once you know that you have to use the multi-linearity of the  determinant, it's easy. Please mark my answer as finished.